# function returns "thisarray" instead of the actual array

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm working on a Wordpress Plugin that will use an API to get a Array of Heros and displays them at the place of a shortcode.

I have a Class

```
class Hero {
  public  $name,
          $time;
}
```

and a function

```
function getHeroList() {
  $Hero1 = new Hero;
  $Hero1->name = "Hero 1";
  $Hero1->time = "5";

  $Hero2 = new Hero;
  $Hero2->name = "Hero 2";
  $Hero2->time = "10";

  $HeroList = [$Hero1, $Hero2];
  return $HeroList;
}
```

now, when debugging infront of the return, the var_dump returns

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(Hero)#2913 (2) { ["name"]=> string(6) "Hero 1" ["time"]=> string(1) "5" } [1]=> object(Hero)#2914 (2) { ["name"]=> string(6) "Hero 2" ["time"]=> string(2) "10" } }
```

When debugging the returned Variable,

```
$output = this.getHeroList();
    var_dump($output);
```

it returns just

```
string(9) "thisArray"
```

can anyone tell me my mistake?
i can not use return type declaration  because i'm not running php7

Comment: You are mixing PHP and Javascript....

Comment: As you probably expect, that doesn't make any sense. You'll have to spend more time debugging this, because the code you've provided certainly doesn't result in `"thisArray"`. There's nothing the general programming community can do to help here.

Comment: As Jeremy said, you're mixing up programming languages here. The correct syntax is `$this->getHeroList()`, and right now you're **concatenating** the **constant** `this` (which is converted to a string automatically if undefined) and the array returned by `getHeroList()` (which is cast to string as `Array`). PHP should be giving you notices about the "use of undefined constant `this`" and "array to string conversion," but I'm assuming you have `E_NOTICE` disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at

```
$output = this.getHeroList();
```

This is no valid PHP. It must be `$output = $this->getHeroList();` if your `getHeroList` ist part of a class, otherwise just `getHeroList();`.

Comment: thanks, commng from to many languages i sometimes get confused

Answer (score 1):

You call to you getHeroList function should simply be:

```
$output = getHeroList();
var_dump($output);
```

I'm not sure why you do this.getHeroList().
$this->getHeroList() would be if it's a class method, and it doesn't seem to be in your example.

You should read up on PHP functions.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php